# Error Export file from PHP Application

Tags: php, download

When I Download my file, it do not display all the details of the data. but when I changed my choices for example I change the date, it works fine and it display all the details.

```
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($this->_filepath).'.csv');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($this->_filepath));
    readfile($this->_filepath);
    exit();
```

is it a problem of the memory ?

Comment: What details of the data? Do you get an empty file? A partially downloaded file? What date do you change? As it is, the question doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Sorry, I was'nt clean in my question. First of all, I import the file xls into my project to visualise the data in the Chart according many parameters like: Date, city, Customer....

Comment: for example the turnover of the month March, I display it in the Chart and I have a bottom to download for example just the turnover of March. The problem is the number of turnover in the Chart always more the number in the file that I downloaded it, and the détails like the names of the customers, the names of city,..... it do not display all. There is problem of Chart or memory ?

Comment: It's impossible for someone to know the answer only with what you say here. The problem could be anywhere! Try to edit your question to add information about the entire process you follow. FYI, reading your comments, I still have no idea what you application is doing or looks like. Debugging complex things can be hard but it is part of the learning process!! It's best to ask specific & answerable questions here, not have extended discussions.